# EFAULT from function in kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel, rootkit

I am trying to compare if two filenames refer to the same file by checking if their inode and device IDs match. Currently, I call `vfs_stat` to obtain the IDs.

The problem is, if I pass `vfs_stat` a filename that's stored in userspace, it works fine, but if I pass it a filename that's stored in as a global variable in my kernel module, it errors with `EFAULT`

Is there any other way to obtain the IDs or compare if two files are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vfs_stat` takes a filename stored in userspace.  But if you trace that call in the source, you'll see (in fs/stat.c) that there are basically two parts.  Lookup the `struct path` from the userspace filename string, then call the VFS stat operation based on the contents of the path struct.  So you can do the same from kernel space.  Look into `kern_path()` to look up the `struct path` for a filename stored in kernel space.  From there, you can call `vfs_getattr()` directly.  Don't forget to `path_put` when you're done.

Basically, you're using the important bits of `vfs_fstatat()`.  But also consider if you can manage without the stat call.  There's an inode pointer somewhere inside the path struct, and that might be good enough for what you're trying to do.